# Qt Creator's project messed up

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qcustomplot

I am trying to add `crypto++` library to `Qt` project in `QtCreator` IDE. I've made a mistake by adding `crypto++` sources to project instead of adding .so library. Thus I've deleted `crypto++` directory from qt projects to regain pre-crypto++ project state, which compiled and linked without problems. Before crypto++ I've also added `QCustomPlot` and compiled and built the project without any errors.Now I cannot recompile and rebuild project anymore because of following errors:

```
09:19:42: Running steps for project ueTestProject...
09:19:42: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
09:19:42: Starting: "/usr/bin/make"
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib -o ueTestProject main.o cmainwindow.o ueborderlayout.o uecentralwidget.o qcustomplot.o uegraphwidget.o uetopmerchandisewidget.o uetopmerchandiseview.o uepossesttings.o   -L/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
cmainwindow.o: In function `CMainWindow::CMainWindow(QWidget*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../cmainwindow.cpp:4: undefined reference to `vtable for CMainWindow'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../cmainwindow.cpp:4: undefined reference to `vtable for CMainWindow'
cmainwindow.o: In function `CMainWindow::~CMainWindow()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../cmainwindow.cpp:23: undefined reference to `vtable for CMainWindow'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../cmainwindow.cpp:23: undefined reference to `vtable for CMainWindow'
uecentralwidget.o: In function `UeCentralWidget::UeCentralWidget(QWidget*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../gui/uecentralwidget.cpp:4: undefined reference to `vtable for UeCentralWidget'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../gui/uecentralwidget.cpp:4: undefined reference to `vtable for UeCentralWidget'
uecentralwidget.o: In function `UeCentralWidget::~UeCentralWidget()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../gui/uecentralwidget.cpp:22: undefined reference to `vtable for UeCentralWidget'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../gui/uecentralwidget.cpp:22: undefined reference to `vtable for UeCentralWidget'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayer::QCPLayer(QCustomPlot*, QString const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:755: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayer'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayer::~QCPLayer()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:761: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayer'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayerable::QCPLayerable(QCustomPlot*, QString, QCPLayerable*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:937: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayerable'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayerable::~QCPLayerable()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:948: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayerable'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayerable::moveToLayer(QCPLayer*, bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:1147: undefined reference to `QCPLayerable::layerChanged(QCPLayer*)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPMarginGroup::QCPMarginGroup(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:1561: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPMarginGroup'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPMarginGroup::~QCPMarginGroup()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:1569: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPMarginGroup'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayoutElement::QCPLayoutElement(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:1753: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayoutElement'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayoutElement::~QCPLayoutElement()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:1757: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayoutElement'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayout::QCPLayout()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:2139: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayout'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayoutGrid::QCPLayoutGrid()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:2501: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayoutGrid'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayoutGrid::~QCPLayoutGrid()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:2505: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayoutGrid'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayoutInset::QCPLayoutInset()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:3095: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayoutInset'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayoutInset::~QCPLayoutInset()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:3099: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayoutInset'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPGrid::QCPGrid(QCPAxis*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:3691: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPGrid'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::QCPAxis(QCPAxisRect*, QCPAxis::AxisType)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4050: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAxis'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::~QCPAxis()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4075: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAxis'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::setScaleType(QCPAxis::ScaleType)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4181: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::scaleTypeChanged(QCPAxis::ScaleType)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::setRange(QCPRange const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4226: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4227: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&, QCPRange const&)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::setSelectableParts(QFlags<QCPAxis::SelectablePart> const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4245: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::selectableChanged(QFlags<QCPAxis::SelectablePart> const&)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::setSelectedParts(QFlags<QCPAxis::SelectablePart> const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4269: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::selectionChanged(QFlags<QCPAxis::SelectablePart> const&)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::setRange(double, double)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4299: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4300: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&, QCPRange const&)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::setRangeLower(double)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4343: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4344: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&, QCPRange const&)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::setRangeUpper(double)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4366: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:4367: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&, QCPRange const&)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::moveRange(double)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:5168: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:5169: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&, QCPRange const&)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::scaleRange(double, double)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:5201: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:5202: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::rangeChanged(QCPRange const&, QCPRange const&)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxis::setupTickVectors()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:5530: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::ticksRequest()'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:5595: undefined reference to `QCPAxis::ticksRequest()'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractPlottable::QCPAbstractPlottable(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:6853: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAbstractPlottable'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractPlottable::setSelectable(bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:7000: undefined reference to `QCPAbstractPlottable::selectableChanged(bool)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractPlottable::setSelected(bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:7023: undefined reference to `QCPAbstractPlottable::selectionChanged(bool)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractItem::QCPAbstractItem(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:8359: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAbstractItem'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractItem::~QCPAbstractItem()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:8369: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAbstractItem'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractItem::setSelectable(bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:8421: undefined reference to `QCPAbstractItem::selectableChanged(bool)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractItem::setSelected(bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:8444: undefined reference to `QCPAbstractItem::selectionChanged(bool)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCustomPlot::QCustomPlot(QWidget*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:9056: undefined reference to `vtable for QCustomPlot'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:9056: undefined reference to `vtable for QCustomPlot'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCustomPlot::~QCustomPlot()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:9106: undefined reference to `vtable for QCustomPlot'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:9106: undefined reference to `vtable for QCustomPlot'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCustomPlot::replot(QCustomPlot::RefreshPriority)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10384: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::beforeReplot()'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10403: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::afterReplot()'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCustomPlot::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10700: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::mouseDoubleClick(QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10707: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::plottableDoubleClick(QCPAbstractPlottable*, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10709: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::axisDoubleClick(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis::SelectablePart, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10711: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::itemDoubleClick(QCPAbstractItem*, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10713: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::legendDoubleClick(QCPLegend*, QCPAbstractLegendItem*, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10715: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::legendDoubleClick(QCPLegend*, QCPAbstractLegendItem*, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10717: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::titleDoubleClick(QMouseEvent*, QCPPlotTitle*)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCustomPlot::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10742: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::mousePress(QMouseEvent*)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCustomPlot::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10764: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::mouseMove(QMouseEvent*)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCustomPlot::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10789: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::mouseRelease(QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10826: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::selectionChangedByUser()'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10833: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::plottableClick(QCPAbstractPlottable*, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10835: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::axisClick(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis::SelectablePart, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10837: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::itemClick(QCPAbstractItem*, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10839: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::legendClick(QCPLegend*, QCPAbstractLegendItem*, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10841: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::legendClick(QCPLegend*, QCPAbstractLegendItem*, QMouseEvent*)'
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10843: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::titleClick(QMouseEvent*, QCPPlotTitle*)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCustomPlot::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:10867: undefined reference to `QCustomPlot::mouseWheel(QWheelEvent*)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxisRect::QCPAxisRect(QCustomPlot*, bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:11749: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAxisRect'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAxisRect::~QCPAxisRect()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:11783: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAxisRect'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractLegendItem::QCPAbstractLegendItem(QCPLegend*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:12668: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAbstractLegendItem'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractLegendItem::setSelectable(bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:12726: undefined reference to `QCPAbstractLegendItem::selectableChanged(bool)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractLegendItem::setSelected(bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:12743: undefined reference to `QCPAbstractLegendItem::selectionChanged(bool)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPPlottableLegendItem::QCPPlottableLegendItem(QCPLegend*, QCPAbstractPlottable*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:12838: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPPlottableLegendItem'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLegend::QCPLegend()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:12966: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLegend'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLegend::~QCPLegend()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:12989: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLegend'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLegend::setSelectableParts(QFlags<QCPLegend::SelectablePart> const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13122: undefined reference to `QCPLegend::selectableChanged(QFlags<QCPLegend::SelectablePart>)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLegend::setSelectedParts(QFlags<QCPLegend::SelectablePart> const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13168: undefined reference to `QCPLegend::selectionChanged(QFlags<QCPLegend::SelectablePart>)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPPlotTitle::QCPPlotTitle(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13536: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPPlotTitle'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPPlotTitle::QCPPlotTitle(QCustomPlot*, QString const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13559: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPPlotTitle'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPPlotTitle::setSelectable(bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13626: undefined reference to `QCPPlotTitle::selectableChanged(bool)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPPlotTitle::setSelected(bool)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13642: undefined reference to `QCPPlotTitle::selectionChanged(bool)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorScale::QCPColorScale(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13841: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPColorScale'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorScale::~QCPColorScale()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13848: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPColorScale'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorScale::setDataRange(QCPRange const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13957: undefined reference to `QCPColorScale::dataRangeChanged(QCPRange)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorScale::setDataScaleType(QCPAxis::ScaleType)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13980: undefined reference to `QCPColorScale::dataScaleTypeChanged(QCPAxis::ScaleType)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorScale::setGradient(QCPColorGradient const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:13998: undefined reference to `QCPColorScale::gradientChanged(QCPColorGradient)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorScaleAxisRectPrivate::QCPColorScaleAxisRectPrivate(QCPColorScale*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:14253: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPColorScaleAxisRectPrivate'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPGraph::QCPGraph(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:14502: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPGraph'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPGraph::~QCPGraph()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:14520: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPGraph'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPCurve::QCPCurve(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:16806: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPCurve'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPCurve::~QCPCurve()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:16822: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPCurve'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPBarsGroup::QCPBarsGroup(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:18068: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPBarsGroup'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPBarsGroup::~QCPBarsGroup()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:18072: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPBarsGroup'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPBars::QCPBars(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:18444: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPBars'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPBars::~QCPBars()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:18457: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPBars'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPStatisticalBox::QCPStatisticalBox(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:19187: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPStatisticalBox'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorMap::QCPColorMap(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:20074: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPColorMap'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorMap::~QCPColorMap()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:20078: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPColorMap'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorMap::setDataRange(QCPRange const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:20126: undefined reference to `QCPColorMap::dataRangeChanged(QCPRange)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorMap::setDataScaleType(QCPAxis::ScaleType)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:20141: undefined reference to `QCPColorMap::dataScaleTypeChanged(QCPAxis::ScaleType)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPColorMap::setGradient(QCPColorGradient const&)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:20164: undefined reference to `QCPColorMap::gradientChanged(QCPColorGradient)'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPFinancial::QCPFinancial(QCPAxis*, QCPAxis*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:20574: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPFinancial'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPFinancial::~QCPFinancial()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:20582: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPFinancial'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemStraightLine::QCPItemStraightLine(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:21404: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemStraightLine'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemStraightLine::~QCPItemStraightLine()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:21413: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemStraightLine'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemLine::QCPItemLine(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:21594: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemLine'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemLine::~QCPItemLine()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:21603: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemLine'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemCurve::QCPItemCurve(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:21829: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemCurve'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemCurve::~QCPItemCurve()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:21840: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemCurve'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemRect::QCPItemRect(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:21983: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemRect'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemRect::~QCPItemRect()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:21994: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemRect'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemText::QCPItemText(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:22142: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemText'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemText::~QCPItemText()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:22159: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemText'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemEllipse::QCPItemEllipse(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:22482: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemEllipse'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemEllipse::~QCPItemEllipse()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:22493: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemEllipse'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemPixmap::QCPItemPixmap(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:22669: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemPixmap'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemPixmap::~QCPItemPixmap()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:22679: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemPixmap'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemTracer::QCPItemTracer(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:22922: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemTracer'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemTracer::~QCPItemTracer()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:22936: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemTracer'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemBracket::QCPItemBracket(QCustomPlot*)':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:23276: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemBracket'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPItemBracket::~QCPItemBracket()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.cpp:23287: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPItemBracket'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayout::~QCPLayout()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.h:719: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPLayout'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPAbstractPlottable::~QCPAbstractPlottable()':
/home/developeruser/projects/ueTestProject/bin/../plot/qcustomplot.h:1388: undefined reference to `vtable for QCPAbstractPlottable'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPLayout* qobject_cast<QCPLayout*>(QObject*)':
/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:520: undefined reference to `QCPLayout::staticMetaObject'
qcustomplot.o: In function `QCPGraph* qobject_cast<QCPGraph*>(QObject*)':
```

These are only some of errors, because I cannot paste them all because of 30000 chars limitation of stack overflow.
Here is also `.pro` file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-02-16T15:51:38
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport sql

TARGET = ueTestProject
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    cmainwindow.cpp \
    layouts/ueborderlayout.cpp \
    gui/uecentralwidget.cpp \
    plot/qcustomplot.cpp \
    gui/uegraphwidget.cpp \
    gui/uetopmerchandisewidget.cpp \
    gui/uetopmerchandiseview.cpp \
    settings/uepossesttings.cpp \
```

What did break up?

Comment: Try to rebuild the project without Qt Creator. `make clean && qmake && make`.

Comment: Is your `.pro` including the crypto++ source files? If yes, probably that is the problem. Remove them and and perform a clean build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deleted whole project (after backing up it up), created new project with same name, added headers and sources in same hierarchy and now works ok! The reason headers were not seen in the project that in `.pro` file `HEADERS` section was somehow deleted.

Answer (score 3):

It seems those errors are caused because the compiler can't find the code that is supposed to be generated by the Qt pre-compiler (MOC). Maybe you still have "trash" from your previous .pro configuration.

It's recommended you clean and recompile the project after you change the .pro file. You can read more about it at [Using the Meta-Object Compiler (moc)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html).

You can try this inside QtCreator:

```
Build > Clean All
Build > Run qmake
Build > Build All
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the include file itself to the project.

So the headers section should also contain qcustomplot.h

Obviously with standard C/C++ compilers (MSVC++ gcc etc.) you don't need to explicitly make the compiler aware of the header, as long as the containing folder is specified. Qt obviously does some extra magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can close QtCreator, remove .pro.user file and Makefile and all other file except source and header files. Then open and configure project again via QtCreator

Comment: I did what you asked, but now I've lost `Headers` folder in QtCreator's project view and the errors are still there.